# Not using node.js : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript

i have this simple js sample which i test via visual studio code with live preview server build in:
i don't use node.js in this sample
all js files under js dir :

```
C:\Dev\my\javascript\ThreeJS\tests\js>ls -1
GLTFLoader.js
OrbitControls.js
main.js
three.js
three.min.js
three.module.js
```

HTML:

but i keep getting this general error :

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scene-container">
            <canvas></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in js/main.js

```
import {
  BoxBufferGeometry,
  Color,
  Mesh,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  WebGLRenderer,
} from 'three';

// Get a reference to the container element that will hold our scene
const container = document.querySelector('#scene-container');

// create a Scene
const scene = new Scene();

// Set the background color
scene.background = new Color('skyblue');

// Create a camera
const fov = 35; // AKA Field of View
const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
const near = 0.1; // the near clipping plane
const far = 100; // the far clipping plane

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

// every object is initially created at ( 0, 0, 0 )
// move the camera back so we can view the scene
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

// create a geometry
const geometry = new BoxBufferGeometry(2, 2, 2);

// create a default (white) Basic material
const material = new MeshBasicMaterial();

// create a Mesh containing the geometry and material
const cube = new Mesh(geometry, material);

// add the mesh to the scene
scene.add(cube);

// create the renderer
const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();

// next, set the renderer to the same size as our container element
renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);

// finally, set the pixel ratio so that our scene will look good on HiDPI displays
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

// add the automatically created <canvas> element to the page
container.append(renderer.domElement);

// render, or 'create a still image', of the scene
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: What do you expect the `three` module to resolve to? [This module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three)? `three.js` in the current folder? `three.js` in the project root folder?

Comment: you need to install ```three``` package. ```npm i -s three```, or include it via a ```cdn``` in your html file.

Comment: but again i said i dont use node js all the tree.js files are in js folder see updated question

Comment: Can you show an example of this on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the below code to my HTML File worked for me.

```
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "three": "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js"
    }
}</script>
```

Credits: https://jsfiddle.net/2nyxkmco/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also make sure to run in local server if using VSCode

Answer (score 17):

The following is my code when using cdn without webpack/node.js.

#index.html

```
<head>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.0/build/three.module.js",
                "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
```

#test.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

scene = new THREE.Scene();
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

ref: https://jspm.org/import-map-cdn

> This is because unlike other web resources, the JS modules specification for HTML reserved the space of these non-relative references (called "bare specifiers") exactly to allow custom package imports via import maps.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Still the same error message.
How to use Three.js correctly on static hosting without NPM? Or use this unpkg.com?

Answer (score 6):

write namespace THREE  and import like this.....

```
  import * as THREE from 'fileUrl';
```

for more info go to this link
https://discoverthreejs.com/book/introduction/get-threejs/

Comment: i can't use import if i dont use node.js ?

Comment: Import statement is used in es6 instead of required statement, so yes you can use this statement if you are not using node.js.

Comment: This solution does not work when I have run on Mozilla Firefox. It causes "Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'fileUrl' from http://localhost:3000/examples/?0
    throwUnresolved https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js:786
    d ....
Need better alterantive solution.

Answer (score 6):

Also since 26th of January this year three.js released r137 update and since r137 using ES6 modules like GLTFLoader in the browser requires an import map.

```
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "three": "../master/three.js-master/build/three.module.js"
    }
}
```

The three.js import statement in your scripts.js looks like so then:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

https://github.com/Kramzin/threejs-task - Here you can see updated and previous code, after these changes everything is working.

Comment: For some reason, my laptop seems not to recognize "importmap" at all, so I have to make direct link to file three.module.js to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question as follows: You want to include the distributed `three.js` file into your HTML file without bundling your code (using e.g. webpack). If that's the case, you should not use `import` in your own code, but rather globally import the dependency (three) into your HTML file. This will expose the THREE object into the global namespace. Then, in your JavaScript file, you automatically have access to the global variables. You can directly access the module (without referencing to it).

Here is an example (taken and adapted from [the official documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/my-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

my-script.js:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

---

To reuse your existing code, you can use the spread operator and break down the global variable into your now imported ones:

```
const {
  BoxBufferGeometry,
  Color,
  Mesh,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  WebGLRenderer,
} = window.THREE;
```

Comment: Thanks ! so webpack is just node.js thing?

Comment: @user63898 webpack is a tool which lets you program for the front-end in regular JavaScript modules, similar to Node.js modules. It then bundles your code together and creates at the end one `.js` file which you can add to your HTML. This file does then contain all your code, but without import/export statements. Webpack uses Node.js as its runtime. The bundled files do not require Node.js anymore though.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using 'three' package from npm thenyou need to install that pakage in terminal and import like this

```
import * as THREE from './js/three.module.js';

or
import {
  BoxBufferGeometry,
  Color,
  Mesh,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  WebGLRenderer,
} from 'three';
```

Comment: see my updated question i dont use node js

Comment: i can't use import if i dont use node.js ?

Comment: you can use import in html without node.js but your script tag musst have type="module"

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for mee..

```
//import * as THREE from 'three'; // somehow this does not work    
import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
```

with following directory structure and installation as per Three.js installation page...

```
/node_modules
index.html
main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to make a correct directory link to file ***three.module.js*** according to the solution from [ThreeJS discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/error-relative-references-must-start-with-either-or/13573) for [Mozilla Firefox case when importmap of script is not working](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-import-map-not-working-in-firefox/35780/6) by changing from:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

to be the correct directory to file ***three.module.js*** according to this example depended upon the place of the html file or javascript file that cause the trouble :

```
import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
```