# How to properly fetch JSON data from an API GET endpoint within a CesiumJS client app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cesiumjs

I'm scratching a vanilla CesiumJS demo application from the [1.73 branch](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/tree/1.73).

I left untouched the `server.cjs` file, but I added one custom client implementation file as `Apps/myproject/my.js`

As I need to GET some JSON responses from an existing API within that demo application, I tried to import the 'https' module as follows:

```js
const https = require('https');
```

which conducted me to the [`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) error.

Then I tried the `import` way:

```js
import https;
```

which raised the `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing keyword 'from' after import clause` error.

(...)

I finally ended up with:

```js
import * as https from 'https';
```

but => [`Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “https”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. my.js:2:18`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697410/not-using-node-js-uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-thre)

I'm running out of ideas for the moment.

How could I successfully and efficiently load and execute an http(s) request to actually get a JSON response from a given API within my custom Cesium app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the "require" statement in the Cesiumjs client app.
Use this code snippet.

```
// replace it with your api url
const url = "https://www.google.com";

const promise = Cesium.Resource.fetchJson({
    url: url,
    queryParameters: {
    }
});

promise.then((response) =>{
  console.log(response);
}).otherwise(error =>{
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, and it's fully working for JSON data. Thanks. I definitely need to update myself on "nowadays JS". I found this resource for that purpose: https://javascript.info/ but let me know if you know about other nice resources for self-learning.