# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MTLLoader is not a constructor 3.0

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
function loadModel(path, objName, mtlName)
{
    var onProgress = function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
        }
    };
    var onError = function(xhr) { };

    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath(path);

    mtlLoader.load(mtlName, function(materials)
    {
        materials.preload();
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath(path);

        objLoader.load(objName, function (object)
        {
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);

            scene.add(object);

        }, onProgress, onError);
    });
}
```

```
<script type="module" src="./js/libs/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="./js/libs/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

I have already tried all the ways that I found on the Internet and none of them helped me, with the solution of one problem, another appeared. I have the latest versions of all libraries installed

Comment: Have you imported the MTLLoader package?

Comment: @eternityparadigm, yes, error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697410/not-using-node-js-uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-thre

Comment: @eternityparadigm Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to parse import map: invalid JSON

Comment: @eternityparadigm and still Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @eternityparadigm I was wrong. Now error: Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MTLLoader is not a constructor. And warning:  Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.

Comment: look for all the places you've imported three.js

Comment: @eternityparadigm GLTFLoader.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at GLTFLoader.js:9:1 and Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'three' does not provide an export named 'SRGBColorSpace' (at MTLLoader.js:12:2)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { MTLLoader } from './libs/MTLLoader.js';
```

Required with `{}`.